# How to point annotation in MKMapView for the large data coming from json? It work fine for around 1000 records

Tags: ios5, annotations, ios6, mkmapview, large-data

I have more than 70,000 record. I want to point that all in mapView,I wrote the code as fallow

```
dispatch_queue_t queue=dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    NSURL* url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?choice=ALL",REQUEST_URL]];
    NSError* error;
    NSData* datapart=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:&error];
    NSDictionary* jsonResponce=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:datapart options:0 error:nil];
    NSString* success=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[jsonResponce objectForKey:@"success"]];

    if([success isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {   
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
            for(NSDictionary* element in [jsonResponce objectForKey:@"locations"])
            {

                MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
                location.latitude = [[element objectForKey:@"lat"]doubleValue];
                location.longitude =[[element objectForKey:@"lon"]doubleValue];


                point.coordinate = location;
                point.title = [element objectForKey:@"name"];

                [mapView addAnnotation:point];

            }
        });
    }
});
```

It crash due to over memory,How can optimise this code and what is the best solution for this Problem?
I received the error as fallow

```
malloc: *** mmap(size=204800) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Comment: The best solution is to not load 70,000 points onto the map, just the ones near where the user is looking.